# Rails nested form (simple_form_for) help has_many belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am using polymorphic relation as i have 3 models like this:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, as: :imageable, foreign_key: :imageable_uuid, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
class MenuPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :image, as: :imageable, foreign_key: :imageable_uuid, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :imageable, foreign_key: :imageable_uuid, :polymorphic => true
end
```

So in my "menu photo form", I put it like this:

```
= simple_form_for @menu_photo do |f|
    = f.simple_fields_for :image_attributes do |d|
        = d.input :photo, as: :file 
        = f.submit
```

When i submit this form, it gives me like this:

```
{"menu_photo"=>{
    "image_attributes"=>
        {"photo"=>"user image upload"}
     }
}
```

It is correct. So in "food form" i do the same:

```
= simple_form_for @food do |f|
    = f.simple_fields_for :images_attributes do |d|
        = d.input :photo, as: :file 
        = f.submit
```

What i expect:

```
{"food"=>{
    "images_attributes"=>[
        {"photo"=>"user image upload one"}, 
        {"photo"=>"user image upload two"}
    ]}
}
```

What i got:

```
{"food"=>{
    "images_attributes"=>
        {"photo"=>"user image upload one"}
     }
}
```

That gives me an error. Any solution about this one?

Comment: what are you mean `the same`? it has same error? if so, post your model and controller for more info to help.

Comment: @KienThanh: It is similar. I want that "link_attributes" to be an array in (has_many belongs_to association), but instead it gave me just a simple hash (i expect an array of hashes). that is what's wrong. Oh by the way, I'm using polymorphic structure.

Comment: No, `has_many` and `belongs_to` association can give many hash as you want (actually, an array of hash, like what you expect). Check this [Class method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). Example, you want a food a with 2 photos, why you get just one photo, because you use only 1 time `@food.photos.build`, if you want more, do this: `n.times { @food.photos.build }` . You can view this [Nested form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for more info.

Comment: @KienThanh: thx man, it works. I've been watching that video many times but now just understood it how it works. But there is a new problem occur. when I apply that to "menu photo form", it gives this error message ("undefined method build for nilClass"). What happen?

Comment: are you have an instance `@food`? If not, create one: `@food = Food.new` before call `n.times { @food.photos.build }` .

Comment: @KienThanh: yes that one work in Food, but for MenuPhoto, its not working. @@menu_photo = MenuPhoto.new. @@menu_photo.image.build

so i got error ("undefined method build")

Comment: change like this: `@menu_photo = MenuPhoto.new`, and `@menu_photo.build_image`, it will work.

Comment: @KienThanh: wow it works, thx. u've been a big help. would u care to explain what is the difference betweent /@food.images.build and /@menu_photo.build_image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you defined `has_many` association:

```
has_many :images
```

`has_many` association will add some methods help you build and create object:

```
collection.build(attributes = {}, …)
collection.create(attributes = {})
```

`collection` here is `images`. You can read more here [has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference)

And when you define `has_one` association:

```
has_one :image
```

`has_one` association will add some methods help you build and create object:

```
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
```

`create_association` here is `image`. You can read more here [has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference).

So, it will have the different way for you to create a new object associated with `has_many` and `has_one`.